# display output streams with python's prompt_toolkit

Tags: python, command-line-interface, prompt-toolkit

I'm trying to capture output a output stream i.e. `dmesg -w` with the prompt_toolkit library[0], but I'm unable to find a good entrypoint.

Creating an `Application()` allows you to pass a `Layout()` which takes Widgets such as `Window` which in turn take `content`. `content` however can't be a stream which refreshes itself.

There is eventloop, but I'm not certain if that's the right direction.

Any hints?

[0] https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html